# check_cpu + nsclient : set critical threshold only on 5min period

Tags: monitor, nagios

I am using centreon (nagios) to monitor the CPUs of some VMs using NSClient. In my case it makes only sense to set the critical state of the cpu probe if the average cpu load is > 95 over the 5m period. Is this achievable ?

I cannot find documentation on how to specify that in the critical param

Default command

```
check_cpu
```

Returns

```
CPU Load ok
'total 5m load'=0%;80;90 'total 1m load'=0%;80;90 'total 5s load'=7%;80;90
```

Command with specific threshold (but all time period can match)

```
check_cpu "critical=load > 90"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what I wanted to do but what I did is the following

```
check_nrpe -u -H XX.XXX.X.XXX -c check_cpu -a "crit=load > 95" "warn=load > 90" time=5m
```

Which limits the output to the 5m time period.

Note that to execute this from centreon you have to set the following variables inside the `nsclient.ini` file (waisted a lot of time on that one)

```
[/settings/NRPE/server]
allow nasty characters=true

[/settings/external scripts]
allow nasty characters=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this script,

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               xxx
    service_description     CPU Load
    check_command           check_nrpe!check_load
    contact_groups          sysadmin
```

}

---

```
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
check_nrpe -u -H XX.XXX.X.XXX -c check_cpu -a "warning=time = '5m' and load > 80" "critical=time = '5m' and load > 90" show-all
```

You can also check [the documentation](https://documentation.centreon.com/) for more info.